# Need help populating an html select with data from a mysql database using php and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html select where the user chooses an option and then clicks go.  What I want to happen next is to bring up another  populated with the data received from a mysql database based on the option they picked in the first select.

I have my code working to where it will run the query get the data and then run success in the ajax call.  The problem is I don't know how to format the data returning so that I am able to populate a html select with it. I figured I need to parse the results from the json returned into an array that can be used to output the select options with each value.  I am not sure how to do this however.  Or if someone has a better suggestion please help.

process.php

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sales_rep", "root", "");


$country = $_POST['q'];


$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT state_prefix
    FROM zips
    WHERE country = '$country'
    ORDER BY state_prefix ASC
    LIMIT 50");


if($stmt->execute()){
    echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ));

} else {
    echo "query fail";
}   

?>
```

rep.js

```
 $('#country').submit(function(event) {

event.preventDefault();



 /*clear result div*/
   $("#result").html('');


  var values = $(this).serialize();



  $.ajax({
  url: "process.php",
  type: "post",
  data: values,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response){
       console.log(response);
  },
  error:function(){
      alert("failure");
      $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
  }   
 }); 



  });
```

Comment: Since you are `json_encode`ing your data and expecting JSOn in your `success` handler, there is no need to parse the results.  Can you just show us what `console.log(response);` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

I used that:

This is my php server:

```
<?php
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data=json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA,true);
$option= $data['option'];
require_once '../../Model/yourmodel.php';
$model= new Model();
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
print json_encode($model->getQueries($option));
?>
```

This is my model:

```
 $data = array();
        try {
            $myconexion= new conexion();
            $cn = $myconexion->connect();
            mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $rs = mysql_query($sql, $cn); //some sql
            while($reg = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
                $data[] = $reg;
            }
            mysql_free_result($rs);
            mysql_close($cn);
        } catch (exception $e) {
            try {
                mysql_free_result($rs);
            } catch (exception $e) {

            }
            try {
                mysql_close($cn);
            } catch (exception $e) {

            }

        }
        return $data;
```

And some client:(jquery)

```
$("#country").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();


    var option = $("#myIDoption").val();
    //my atributes
    var jsonCliente = {
        option : option,
      };

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonCliente),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../backend/someurl.php",
        success: function ( data ) {
          //example of json result
          /*
          [{"idtb_producto":"3","name":"ENFERMEDADES ENDEMICAS EN EL PERU",
          "stock":null,"buyprice":null},{"idtb_producto":"4","name":
          "ENFERMEDADES PARASITARIAS","stock":null,"buyprice":null}]    
          */
             $.each(data, function(i) {
               var nombre = data[i].name;
               var stock = data[i].stock;
               var price = data[i].buyprice;
               //do something with my data
            });

        }
    });

    return false;
 });
```

I hope this information helps you : D